# How to use same vector drawable with different sizes

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have created a vector drawable of a material icon https://material.io/icons/#ic_chat_bubble in my android application. 
I've created the vector drawable of size 18*18 dp, but I have to use the same drawable in size 24*24 and 36*36 also. I know that I can change the color of the vector drawable by using the setTint function. But how can I change the size of vector drawable, so that I can use the same vector drawable with different sizes.

Please help if anyone know how to do it. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a drawable for each size?